# json_decode() returns NULL on valid JSON, but json_last_error() is 0?

Tags: php, json

I'm reading in simple, valid JSON data from a local file:

```
{
  "title": "...",
  "author": "...",
  "published": "...",
  "updated": "...",
  "imageCredit": "..."
}
```

which var_dump($jsonData) shows as

```
string(103) "{ "title": "...", "author": "...", "published": "...", "updated": " ", "imageCredit": "..." }"
```

The code

```
$metaData = json_decode($jsonData,true);
```

yields NULL, while json_last_error() is 0.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing/doing wrong in creating a valid PHP object here?

Comment: Has the json been edited in any Microsoft word processor? Could be BOM characters hidden in there

Comment: Paste the json into a hex editor to check for BOM characters

Comment: do you need object try json_decode($jsonData);

Comment: I copy and pasted your string, and it encoded just fine.

Comment: Hmmm...not sure what the actual problem was; after sleeping on it, I came back this morning, tried a few of the suggestions, including the encode->decode round trip, and as far as I can tell, I'm back where I started (the file's not yet under version control, so I can't diff it), but whatever I did, it's now working.  I'm guessing I had a typo somewhere that went unnoticed, or perhaps omg kumar's suggestion was the winner; I'm not sure.  

Can someone tell me why my question was downvoted?

Answer (score -2):

Firstly convert your string data to **JSON**

```
$jsonData = json_encode($jsonDataString);
```

Then **Decode** it to get Associative Array :

```
json_decode($jsonData, true);
```

**Or**

```
json_decode(json_encode($jsonDataString), true);
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: JSON encoding _a string_ won't do anything useful. Round-tripping one through JSON encode/decode is even less useful.